# Algebraic $n$-torus and topological $n$-torus

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Working with the field $\mathbb C$, one can find two different objects called "torus":

**- Algebraic $n$-Torus** that is $(\mathbb C^\ast)^n$

**- Topological $n$-Torus** defined (for example) as the quotient group $\mathbb C^n/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\mathbb C^n$.

What is the relation between these two objects? (Certainly the algebraic torus contains the topological torus.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- They're homotopy equivalent.
- The latter can be thought of as the [maximal compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) subgroup of the former; in that sense they stand in a relationship analogous to the relationship between $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (algebraic) and $\text{U}(n)$ (topological), and indeed the algebraic torus is the subgroup of diagonal matrices in the former and the topological torus is the subgroup of diagonal matrices in the latter.
- They have the same representation theory in a suitable sense (which is also true for $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\text{U}(n)$).
- The Lie algebra of the former is the complexification of the Lie algebra of the latter.